# How to programmatically focus on the next cell after adding a new row in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new to angular coming from the Knockout world. I have hooked into a key-press event for tab in order to add a new  in the last cell in the table.

My issue is that the focus then goes into information icon in the uri bar rather then next cell in the newly created row. I am sure the fix is simple I just can not find the solution, Can anyone help?

I am using Angularjs v1.59

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp
    .factory('shippingItems', function () {
        return {
            data: [{
                quantity: 1,
                width: 1,
                height: 1,
                length: 1,
                weight: 1,
                details: 1
            },
            {
                quantity: 2,
                width: 2,
                height: 2,
                length: 2,
                weight: 2,
                details: 2
            },
            {
                quantity: 3,
                width: 3,
                height: 3,
                length: 3,
                weight: 3,
                details: 3
            }]
        };
    })
    .controller("userCtrl", ['$scope', 'shippingItems', function ($scope, shippingItems) {
            $scope.shippingItems = shippingItems.data;
    }])
    .directive("myTab", ['shippingItems', function (shippingItems) {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.index = attrs.indexTracker;
                element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
                    if (scope.index == (shippingItems.data.length-1)) {
                        if (event.which === 9) {
                            var newItem = {
                                quantity: null,
                                width: null,
                                height: null,
                                length: null,
                                weight: null,
                                details: null
                            };
                            shippingItems.data.push(newItem);
                            element.next().focus();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">lol</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Width x Height x Length (cm)</th>
                            <th>Weight Per Item</th>
                            <th>Total Weight</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="table-input" ng-repeat="item in shippingItems">
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.quantity" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.width" /> x <input type="text" ng-model="item.height" /> x <input type="text" ng-model="item.length" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.weight" />kg</td>
                            <td>{{ (item.weight|number) * (item.quantity|number)}}kg</td>
                            <td my-tab="checking" index-tracker="{{$index}}"><input type="text" ng-model="item.details" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: element.bind("keydown keypress",function(){})
Here the element must be input,textarea or contenteditablediv other wise we cannot bind the keypress(in this exapmle yout listening for td is not possible)..one more you are updating factory values only only u have update scope.shippingItems.push(data)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `directive` actually what you want is a `service` however in this sample you can see how to use `angular.element` with passing `$event` from your last `input` in `li` OR `td`.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.ul = [{}, {}, {}]

  $scope.callService = function(event, index) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      var nextInext = index + 1;

      if (angular.isUndefined($scope.ul[nextInext])) {
        $scope.ul.push({});
      }

      $timeout(function() {
        angular.element(event.target).closest(".parent").find(".child-" + nextInext + " input").select();
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <h5>auto focus on next input, auto push [press Enter on inputs]</h5>
  
  <ol class="parent">
    <li ng-repeat="li in ul" class="child-{{$index}}">
      <input type="text" ng-keydown="callService($event, $index)" ng-model="li.input" />
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: The answer is nearly what I am after. However I am using Angularjs v1.5.9 and .closest is not available. is there something else I can use in that version?

Comment: Add jQuery to get closest! Only jQuery has

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp
    .factory('shippingItems', function () {
        return {
            data: [{
                quantity: 1,
                width: 1,
                height: 1,
                length: 1,
                weight: 1,
                details: 1
            },
            {
                quantity: 2,
                width: 2,
                height: 2,
                length: 2,
                weight: 2,
                details: 2
            },
            {
                quantity: 3,
                width: 3,
                height: 3,
                length: 3,
                weight: 3,
                details: 3
            }]
        };
    })
    .controller("userCtrl", ['$scope', 'shippingItems', function ($scope, shippingItems) {
            $scope.shippingItems = shippingItems.data;
    }])
    .directive("myTab", ['shippingItems', function (shippingItems,$timeout) {
        console.log('CALLED')
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("keydown", function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                scope.index = attrs.indexTracker;
                    if (scope.index == (shippingItems.data.length-1)) {
                        //if (event.keyCode === 81 && event.altKey) {
                        if (event.keyCode === 9) {
                            var newItem = {
                                quantity: null,
                                width: null,
                                height: null,
                                length: null,
                                weight: null,
                                details: null
                            };
                            shippingItems.data.push(newItem);
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                var tr_dom      = element[0].closest('tr').nextElementSibling
                                var input       = element[0].closest('tr').nextElementSibling.querySelector('input')
                                input.focus()
                             },10);
                            scope.$apply()
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="userCtrl">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">lol</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Width x Height x Length (cm)</th>
                            <th>Weight Per Item</th>
                            <th>Total Weight</th>
                            <th>Details</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="table-input" ng-repeat="item in shippingItems">
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.quantity"/></td>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.width" /> x <input type="text" ng-model="item.height" /> x <input type="text" ng-model="item.length" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" ng-model="item.weight" />kg</td>
                            <td>{{ (item.weight|number) * (item.quantity|number)}}kg</td>
                            <td ><input type="text" index-tracker="{{$index}}" ng-model="item.details" my-tab="checking"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```